c# winformchart symmetric majorgrid
I need to display some graphs that have x=0 about in the middle. I would like to align the major gridlines accordingly, e.g. that one of those gridline is at exactly x=0, instead of the default where the grid starts at the first data point.
I have already tried all kinds of combinations of setting the following, but I could get the major grid to move.
Graph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset
Graph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffsetType
Graph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset
Graph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType

What I currently have:

About what I want (line at x=0, the other lines don't have to be at specific values):


@Sinatr that doesn't do anything

You may need to take full control by switching to CustomLabels.

You need to set correct values of AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset and AxisX.Minimum.
Let's demostrate it with some example. Just add a Chart control to a new form and then in constructor:
var series = new Series
{
    ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line,
};

series.Points.AddXY(-5, 5);
series.Points.AddXY(0, 0);
series.Points.AddXY(3, 3);

var x = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
x.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red; // to see major grid better
//x.Minimum = -10;
//x.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = -5;

chart1.Series.Add(series);

Such points make this serie assymetric and by default major grid lines may not go through y = 0. To control offset we need to add offset MajorGrid.IntervalOffset (typically by setting it to the X of the first point) and in addition to specify minimum X of axis (also needs to be equal to the X of the first point or a multiple of it).
On the left - default grid, on the right with offset and minimum:
 

that just moves the data and the major grid to the right by a small amount that is definitely not equal to the provided offset, i.e. the the relative position of the data and x grid lines didn't change

Please refer to [mcve], you have to show your exact case. I was hoping the provided help would be enough for you to continue on your own.
